# Create Grid collage in android

Tags: android, grid

I am working on a collage maker app. I have made Free collage successfully. Now I want to make grid collage. I have array of Image urls and I want to show these images in grid template of more than one designs. So what should I do for this approach.I have to make Grid Template Like this or may be with angled inner edges.

[image]

I have made this by using Grid Layout, it is successfully made but problem arrive when I am trying to make it like second Image

[image]

Please Help me I am stucking here for long time, Thanks.

Comment: Hello @Balvinder Singh Can you guide me how did u achieved Grid Collage I'm facing the same problem. Thank you in Advance

Answer (score -1):

Begin with an example from Google. There are plenty of step by step examples: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: hello @malcubierre will you please provide me some link of example like this